# OpenGL blending not working with DIB section

Tags: c++, opengl

I’m trying to render to a DIB section with blending using OpenGL on XP. I’m trying to multiply the source and destination colour components together, as in:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
```

However, it fails to draw a blended image. By changing the type of blending I ask for, I can make it draw as if without blending, or not draw at all. But it refuses to blend.

Here are details about the OpenGL version I’m using:

```
Vendor: Microsoft Corporation
Renderer: GDI Generic
Version: 1.1.0
Extensions: GL_WIN_swap_hint GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_paletted_texture
```

I was aware that I’m limited to “generic” (software) rendering with DIB sections, but I did not expect blending to fail. I have searched for confirmation about whether blending is or is not supported in such cases, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

```
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
               ^^^ oh?
```

[Transparency, Translucency, and Blending](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm):

> 15.060 **I want to use blending but can’t get destination alpha to work.** Can I blend or create a transparency effect without destination alpha?
>
> Many OpenGL devices don't support destination alpha. **In particular, the OpenGL 1.1 software rendering libraries from Microsoft don't support it.** The OpenGL specification doesn't require it.

Also:

[No Alpha in the Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes#No_Alpha_in_the_Framebuffer):

> If you are doing Blending and you need a destination alpha, you need to make sure that your render target has one. This is easy to ensure when rendering to a Framebuffer Object. But with a Default Framebuffer, it depends on how you created your OpenGL Context.
>
> For example, if you are using GLUT, you need to make sure you pass `GLUT_ALPHA` to the `glutInitDisplayMode` function.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am aware that destination alpha is not available is this case. However, as I thought I had made clear in my question, I am not asking OpenGL to use destination alpha, or even to do alpha blending at all. I am attempting to modulate the source and destination RGB values together using blending. What I’d like to know is whether there is a trick to making this work, or it’s simply not possible with this version of OpenGL. If you think my code is wrong, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made a silly mistake: I misread my own script code and ended up applying the texture in the wrong rendering pass. OpenGL wasn’t to blame, and blending DOES work.